# RegisterMethodInfo and RegisterParamInfo from Delphi XE synonyms in Delphi 2006

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe, delphi-2006

my problem is the following. I have a web service that i have to call, but it contains complex types that Delphi 2006 does not recognize. I tried to import the wsdl through delphi xe and it did a good job. The problem is that I have to use this in Delphi 2006, and the methods that delphi 2006 does not recognize are RegisterMethodInfo and RegisterParamInfo from invokeRegistry. Do they have synonyms or another way that I can execute them in 2006. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project.

With RAD Studio 2007 looks like this.
Look whether "soap" is available

[image]

If "SOAP" does not exist. Install it.

Component - Install Packages

c:\Program Files\CodeGear\RADStudio\4.0\Bin\dclsoap??.bpl.

Goto
`File->New->Other->Web Services->`

if it looks like

[image]

Put a `TWSDLHTMLPublish` to your Form.

[image]

go again to `File->New->Other->Web Services->`

If it looks now with `WSDL Importer`.

[image]

Then you're finished. :-)

Now you can try to import the wsdl through delphi 2006.

Comment: my problem is not that I can't use wsdl import in D2006, the problem is that in D2006 i can not load complex types from the wsdl, that's why I use Delphi XE

Comment: @dzibul : pity that I could not help.